# Is it possible to give the "<apex:relatedList>" the inline edit properties?

Tags: apex, visualforce, related-list

Sort of similar to how  has the ability to set Inline Edit true. Like this -

```
<apex:detail inlineEdit="true" title="false" id="ApprenticeListview" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to this is **No**.

There is no such attribute supporting inline edit for `apex:relatedList`. You can find the complete list of supported attributes for this markup on its [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm
only specific tags suppot inlineEdit. apex:relatedList is not included.